# SQL Server CE 4.0 not updating immediately after call to Fill

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am attempting to update a row in the database relatively often, about once per second, but SQL Server CE seems to be ignoring a majority of the updates until it feels like actually committing one of the updates.

If I debug the code and sit on the `Fill(ds);` line, and step over it, then check the database, it will have updated every time.

It seems like because I'm updating often, it is arbitrarily ignoring some of the updates and eventually just committing one after 5-10 seconds of processing.

**I am wondering** if there is something with SQL Server CE 4.0 that would cause this, or if there is some property of the adapter that needs to be set in order to push the updates instantly?

**It is usually** just one column being updated, which is essentially a counter, so for each `++` there will be an update to the current row. It will generally take 5+ calls until it *actually* updates that column, however, if I increase the time between each call to say 3-5 seconds, it will commit every change to that column.

Edit:

The code is really just:

```
bool isPass = false;
int iCount = 0;

if (EnsureConnectionOpen()) {
    while (!isPass && (iCount++ < 3)) {
        try {
            cmd.Prepare();
            CreateDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            isPass = true;
        }
    }
}
```

With some `catch` logic below, but I'm not generating any exceptions here.

`CreateAdapter` is spitting out `cmd` as an `SqlCeCommand`, which contains parameters.

The SQL is a standard update statement (which is `cmd.CommandText`):

```
UPDATE someTable 
SET column1 = @param1, 
    column2 = @param2. . .
```

Transaction code:

```
SqlCeTransaction trans = (cmd.Connection as SqlCeConnection).BeginTransaction();
cmd.Transaction = trans;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
trans.Commit(CommitMode.Immediate);
```

I am using the `as SqlCeConnection` cast because the `cmd` object comes into the function as a `DbCommand` initially.

Comment: can you show the actual code where you are doing the `Update` also are you issuing an explicit `Commit` I think you should provide more relevant code that pertains to the UPDATE just showing `Fill(ds)` implies that you are returning rows from a select..

Comment: I didn't put much code because the code is pretty standard and works just fine, as I said, "if I increase the time between each call to say 3-5 seconds, **it will commit every change to that column.**". I will however see what relevant code I can include.

Comment: this is still pretty hard to determine without seeing what you timeout is and update statement looks like etc.. are you doing this from C# side or is the update being performed in a stored proc..? you're leaving a lot of room for guess work

Comment: I've included most that I can include, though I don't have any "timeouts", at least none that I have set myself.

Comment: you can override that by default most databases have a 20 or 30 second timeout can you show the update statement as well

Comment: I did include the update statement, it's exactly that except I've removed the specific column names, and there are 13 columns in total. And of course where is a `WHERE idColumn = @param_ID` on the end.

Comment: so I assume you have no `Commit` thus you are relying on the database to issue and or perform an `Implicit Commit` what happens when you issue an explicit `Commit`

Comment: Inside the `cmd` object I can do `cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction().Commit()`. Is this what I should call? And should it be before or after the call to `Fill`?

Comment: see..once again you are leaving a lot of room for guess work. this is why I mentioned earlier that you need to show all relevant code. also I personally would create a stored procedure to do `UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, and SELECT` statements.. if you are doing this in a Transaction then where are you doing the `Transaction.RollBack` in case of an error..?

Comment: There is no transaction. I'm saying the only place something called `Commit` is available is where I mentioned in the previous comment. The code you see above is _**exactly**_ how the data is being inserted into the database. Otherwise, `Transaction` appears no where in my code.

Comment: I personally do not like to use the `Fill()` method to do Updates or Inserts I reserve that for `SELECT Statements` and working off of a stored procedure you probably could have had this refactored and completed by now. for all you know there could be an error happening where only partial updates are being done because of an implicit Rollback

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting, that there's some massive, unknown bug in .NET/Visual Studio 2013/C# that doesn't allow exceptions to be caught...? I think the problem is you didn't actually read my original post carefully enough. The code works all the time, every time, it is just unnecessarily slow when updated rapidly... Anyway, perhaps I'll not use Fill

Comment: I read your question.. and if you expect the database to update in a blink of an eye doing bulk updates vs setting a longer time range.. then perhaps it's not the .net side have you considered the possibility that it's the `sql server ce` issue do you have access to Sql Server at all..? try running the same code base against that.. and see if it yields the same results.. good luck

Comment: Funny enough, this exact code is used to interact with an SQL Server instance as well, and no, this behaviour is not observed. Only with the local SQL CE copy of the database. There are known bugs with SQLCE 4.0 that are labelled "will not fix" on technet by Microsoft, so I guess I'm stuck with this anyway.

Comment: that sucks ... well at least you know it's not a Code issue. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CE only flushes to disk at intervals, and it can be changed via the connection string:

"Specified the interval time (in seconds) before all committed transactions are flushed to disk. If not specified, the default value is 10."

Do not include the setting in your connection string, you will risk loosing data: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2016/02/sql-server-compact-40-sp1-hotfix.html

You can force it to flush by wrapping in a SqlCeTransaction with a CommitMode of Immediate.

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/05/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_21.html

Comment: Since yesterday I've actually been messing around with both of these to see what affect they have. Right now I have both in there, `FLUSH INTERVAL=1` in my `ConnectionString` and I am trying to work with the `Transactions` as well. I've edited some code into my original post, I'm just wondering if that is the correct syntax for using `Transactions`. And I should stick with that and get rid of the `FLUSH INTERVAL`?

Comment: Actually do you know the difference between `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private`. It's not clear why there are two different versions of the same dll's.

Comment: See my blogpost for usage of SqlCeTransaction. Do NOT use flush interval (as stated in my reply)  - and the two different dlls: one has assembly version 4,0,0,0 and is in GAC, the private one has assembly version 4,0,0,1 and is not in GAC...

Comment: Ok I'll remove the flush interval. As far as the two dll's, when I look at their details I'm seeing `File version: 4.0.8902.1` for both. It seems that using either should be fine?

Comment: File version and assembly version are two very different things. So no to your last Q

Comment: I suppose I could start a new question, but do you have any information available on the compiler whining about "No way to resolve conflict between "System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" and "System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0"

I don't understand the message as there is **no where** in any part of the solution where version 3.5.1.0 is referenced.

Comment: Pls start a new q, this is getting out of hand - something in your solution reference 3,5!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not referenced anywhere. Even searching the raw text of all the .csproj files and app.config files returns nothing referencing that assembly. Anyway, I started a new question, thanks for your help.